# Generating documents with templating from a form

Tags: documents, templates, forms

I would like to create a document generator with templating.
The workflow should be as following:

1. The user input data to a static form (simple text input).
2. The user chooses a graphically designed template.
3. A document with the chosen template containing the user data is generated.

The initial templates repository is prepared in advance, but it should be easy to add new templates to the process.

I have the full MS Office suite and the preferred file format is an MS .doc.
I can do a little VB scripting if needed, but I prefer not to.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Anna

Answer (score 1):

the easiest thing i can think of is to make each document style a 'sheet' in excel file. the first sheet being the 'input data to a static form' and they thus can print it easily, or (copy and paste as values..)

Comment: The output document should have a formal look, something like a resume, so I believe excel is not sufficient.